# How is polarity calculated for a sentence ??? (in sentiment analysis)

Tags: nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

How is polarity of words in a statement are calculated....like

"i am successful in accomplishing the task,but in vain"

how each word is scored? (like - successful- 0.7 accomplishing- 0.8 but - -0.5
vain - - 0.8) 
how is it calculated ? how is each word given a value or score?? what is the thing that's going behind ? As i am doing sentiment analysis I have few thing to be clear so .that would be great if someone helps.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use Python and NLTK, then check out Vader (http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html and skip down to the Vader section)

Comment: thanks Tom Winch ...the thing i want to know is exactly not the approach but how polarity is calculated..how is the scoring done for each word in the sentence                         Example from your link provided                        " I won't say that the movie is astounding and I wouldn't claim that the movie is too banal either. " 
compound: 0.4215, neg: 0.0, neu: 0.851, pos: 0.149,

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you google around NLTK and sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The scores from individual words can come from predefined word lists such as ANEW, General Inquirer, SentiWordNet, LabMT or my AFINN. Either individual experts have scored them or students or Amazon Mechanical Turk workers. Obviously, these scores are not the ultimate truth.

Word scores can also be computed by supervised learning with annotated texts, or word scores can be estimated from word ontologies or co-occurence patterns.

As for aggregation of individual words, there are various ways. One way would be to sum all the individual scores (valences), another to take the max valence among the words, a third to normalize (divide) by the number of words or by the number of scored words (i.e., getting a mean score), - or divide the square root of that number. The results may differ a bit.
I made some evaluation with my AFINN word list: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6028/pdf/imm6028.pdf

Another approach is with recursive models like Richard Socher's models. The sentiment values of the individual words are aggregated in a tree-like structure and should find that the "but in vain"-part of your example should carry the most weight.

Comment: Thanks Finn Arup Nielsen ..So can't we know how the words are assigned values and polarity is calculated

Comment: The way I did it was to score words between -5 and 5 by my prior knowledge of Danish and English and by looking at how it was used, particularly on Twitter. You will usually find details in the research papers associated with the word lists that explain about the assignment of values. There is usually no magic involved.