# Vader Sentiment Analysis: How are the individual words rated?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

So I was using Vader Sentiment Analyser to analyse certain customer feedbacks. While assessing the output i saw that the sentiment analyser was giving me mixed results.

```
For eg: "Again, human interaction needs to have resolutions. Your reps 
        cannot BLAME the system and shrug off being able to help. Let 
        alone blame the system and not know WHY the system makes 
        indiscriminate decisions."

Output: compound: 0.2212 neg: 0.111 neu: 0.756, pos: 0.133
```

The O/P in this case should have been negative but instead it gave a compound score of more towards neutral to positive score which makes no sense.

I saw this file in AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\sentiment\vader_lexicon.txt which contained sentiment scores of most of the english words.

I Just wanted to know how these individual words are given sentiment scores in terms of pos neg neu and compound? Is there any algorithm/process to rate them?

Finally, I was thinking of building my own dictionary for sentiment analysis  to get some better results, but for that i need to know how are each words assigned sentiment scores?

Answer (score 7):

Using the below code (not mine), you can determine which words the vader lexicon is classifying as positive, negative, and neutral:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sentence = 'Again, human interaction needs to have resolutions. Your reps cannot BLAME the system and shrug off being able to help. Let alone blame the system and not know WHY the system makes indiscriminate decisions.'
tokenized_sentence = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
pos_word_list=[]
neu_word_list=[]
neg_word_list=[]

for word in tokenized_sentence:
    if (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) >= 0.1:
        pos_word_list.append(word)
    elif (sid.polarity_scores(word)['compound']) <= -0.1:
        neg_word_list.append(word)
    else:
    neu_word_list.append(word)                

print('Positive:',pos_word_list)        
print('Neutral:',neu_word_list)    
print('Negative:',neg_word_list) 
score = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
print('\nScores:', score)
```

Running this code produces the following outcome:

```
Positive: ['help']
Neutral: ['Again', ',', 'human', 'interaction', 'needs', 'to', 'have', 'resolutions', '.', 'Your', 'reps', 'can', 'not', 'the', 'system', 'and', 'shrug', 'off', 'being', 'able', 'to', '.', 'Let', 'the', 'system', 'and', 'not', 'know', 'WHY', 'the', 'system', 'makes', 'indiscriminate', 'decisions', '.']
Negative: ['BLAME', 'alone', 'blame']
```

We can then go to the vader .txt file, and find what scores your words have been appointed. Blame receives a score of -1.4, alone a score of -1.0, and help a score of +1.7. This should produce a negative score, however you have the word 'cannot' before one use of the word blame, which negates the negative element of the word, and instead converts it to positive. Although Vader is clever, it can identify negation however cannot link that back to the overall structure of the sentence (which is true for the majority of alternative methods).

As for an overview of how Vader is working, it relies on summarising the sentiment intensity of various words throughout a sentence, which produces an overall score. There are subtle nuances built-into Vader to transcend the classifier beyond traditional bag-of-words methods, including the addition of negation words and commonly used-terms. In terms of word-sentiment-scores, you'll find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740052/how-is-polarity-calculated-for-a-sentence-in-sentiment-analysis).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But is there any way of making the vader understand the whole context of what's being talked about in a sentence? Because that's what is required to get satisfactory results.

Comment: I believe that is outside the scope of what Vader can do, if you want to take the lexicon-based approach further then you'll need to find a technique which can effectively parse sentences into their grammatical trees.

Answer (score 1):

The individual scores for each word can be found [here](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vader_lexicon.txt).

The scores you get from running `sid.polarity_scores(individual_word)` is the individual score after it has been 'normalized' ([VaderConstants.normalize](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sentiment/vader.html#VaderConstants.normalize)) to a score between [-1,1]. This is not necessarily the score of the word in a sentence since the score can be modified by the surrounding words.

Calculating the score for a sentence involves (at a high level):

1. Assigning a value to each word (after removing the stopwords) based on the data found [here](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment/blob/master/vaderSentiment/vader_lexicon.txt).
2. Manipulating scores for individual words based on rules (e.g. flipping polarity after a negation)
3. Combining individual scores
4. Making additional changes to the combined scores based on more rules (e.g. if there is an exclamation mark at the end of the sentence)

If we simply use `polarity_scores(individual_word)['compound']`, the score may not have the score as when the word is used in a sentence since Vader modifies the score based on the surrounding words. Also, after the scores from all the words are combined in step 3, we lose track of the scores assigned to the individual words. What we can do, however, is to pull the scores out after step 2. In many cases, step 4 doesn't apply so the scores from step 2 go straight into the normalization function.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer, SentiText, VaderConstants

text = "The movie was not great."

# Code from SentimentIntensityAnalyzer.polarity_scores with minor modifications
# https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/sentiment/vader.html#SentimentIntensityAnalyzer.polarity_scores

sentitext = SentiText(text, VaderConstants.PUNC_LIST, VaderConstants.REGEX_REMOVE_PUNCTUATION)

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

sentiments = []
words_and_emoticons = sentitext.words_and_emoticons
for item in words_and_emoticons:
    valence = 0
    i = words_and_emoticons.index(item)
    if (
        i < len(words_and_emoticons) - 1
        and item.lower() == "kind"
        and words_and_emoticons[i + 1].lower() == "of"
    ) or item.lower() in VaderConstants.BOOSTER_DICT:
        sentiments.append(valence)
        continue

    sentiments = sid.sentiment_valence(valence, sentitext, item, i, sentiments)

sentiments = sid._but_check(words_and_emoticons, sentiments)
print(list(zip(words_and_emoticons,sentiments)))
print("Total score after 'normalizing' individual scores:", sid.score_valence(sentiments, text))
```

Using the examples below, note how the score for the word for great is negative when it appears after 'not' and positive otherwise.

To get the score in a negated context the normal score is put through a function, hence the slightly different absolute scores for the word "good'.

Output for "The movie was not great."

```
[('The', 0), ('movie', 0), ('was', 0), ('not', 0), ('great', -2.294)]
Total score after 'normalizing' individual scores: {'neg': 0.452, 'neu': 0.548, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.5096}
```

Output for "The movie was great."

```
[('The', 0), ('movie', 0), ('was', 0), ('great', 3.1)]
Total score after 'normalizing' individual scores: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.423, 'pos': 0.577, 'compound': 0.6249}
```